# Which files occupy 6GB after building mysql-5.7.19

Tags: mysql

I build & install mysql-community-server 5.7.19 from general linux source code on a vmware machine with ubuntu 16 .

After executing make directive , I discover the vmware disk reduces nearly 4G.
After executing make install directive , the vmware disk reduces nearly 2G.
But I use du directive to check that mysql source folder just occupies 1.5G , and mysql install folder occupies 400MB .
[image: picture about msyql folders]

So which files occupy the surplus 4GB space ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Does `du -sh /` match `df -h /`?

Comment: Thanks !  Size 9.3 ,Used 4.5 !  But why does the vmware disk reduced several GB space after I executed make & make install directive ?

Comment: What do you mean by "the vmware disk reduces nearly 4G"? It got bigger or it got smaller?

Comment: I executed make directive twice ! At the first time I used ctrl+c while it stoped at 46% , then I reboot OS and executed make clean directive , then I executed make directive again to finish the installing.

Comment: I`m sorry ! the vmware disk became bigger , my windows disk reduced

Comment: The vmware disk, or the host file that holds the virtual disk? There might have been lots of temporary files that we needed during the build, but they were deleted. But vmware disks don't shrink.

Comment: the host file ,I think

Comment: Do you know where is the temporary files during the build ?

Comment: Probably either /var/tmp or in a temporary folder in your current directory.

Comment: Usually `make` displays all the commands it's running, so you should see where it's creating files.

Comment: How do I  express appreciation to you? I`m not familiar with stackoverflow .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you build that from your own and don't install it from the repository? That make much more sense especially for updates.

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.7
```

Then you have that version. MySQL 5.7.19 is in the repos.

https://packages.ubuntu.com/de/xenial/mysql-server-5.7

Comment: Because I have a little obsession about how it work , and I am really sorry about that !